# Java.utils.cuncurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException:no server to serve request. Check log for details

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, android-studio-3.0

How to fix this error. I am using android studio on my phone using Linux deploy and Ubuntu. Installed open jdk not oracle jdk.  This error comes when building apk. Before that gradle build is successful. Log is too big i don't know where to start

```
Java.utils.cuncurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException:no server to serve request. Check log for detail
```

Edit: This error shown in gradle console

```
AAPT err(faced for 340422075): /root/android/sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/aapt2 :I : /root/android/sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/aapt2 :syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is due to using build tools which does not support on arm platforms. Currently there is no build tools available for arm officially from google. This doesn't provide solution but i need to port build tools for arm.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, OMG congrats on running android studio on your phone, first time I have ever heard of anyone getting this far! :)

This error from AAPT2 comes when you try to run it on 32 bit Linux - it is not a supported platform. 
List of supported platforms: [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads)

Comment: Thanks for the compliment. I have  installed arm64 version of linux.  i tried to execute the file directly by ./aapt2 just to know what will happen.  `Cannot execute binary: It gave exec format error`

Comment: `uname -m` gives `aarch64` as output

Comment: Can you run "/root/android/sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/aapt2 compile" and post the output?

Comment: This is what I was able to find: https://askubuntu.com/questions/648555/bash-program-cannot-execute-binary-file-exec-format-error

Comment: I think i need sdk for arm devices which does not exist

Comment: :( I guess it's not the most common use-case... if it makes you feel any better, you've probably gone the furthest anyone ever has! If you really need to develop on your phone instead of a laptop/computer, you could try using AIDE or DroidScript? More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429689/is-it-possible-to-run-android-studio-on-an-android-tablet